# SharePoint Designer 2013 Access Denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-365, sharepoint-designer-workflow

When trying to save a custom workflow to an Office 365 SharePoint Team Site I get the following error:

[image: Server error: Access denied]

I am currently a site owner, and we have ensured scripts are enabled on the site collection.

Why would a site owner not have access to save workflows on SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

1.Assign Full Control permission directly to the affected user account.

2.Clear the cache of the SharePoint Designer.

3.Open SharePoint Designer and connect to the site collection again, when it’s prompting to input the login account, make sure the Keep me signed in is checked.

More information:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-saving-error/d0ab325b-314f-42b5-956d-822f717e995a
https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/access-denied-while-creating-a-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-permission-issue/